# Can the flag for migration be generalized?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flagging, close-reasons, migration

When flagging a question as needing migration to academia, electronics, signal processing, chemistry, philosophy etc, I end up at Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic>Migration which offers me just two options for migration: math stack exchange, or meta physics stack exchange. I then have to go all the way back to flagging it again, choosing the "other" option, and then typing in the migration site.

Would it therefore be possible to replace the two migration options with a general box where people can type in the site they think the question needs to be migrated to?

Comment: I agree with this post completely. However, it has been proposed before, e.g.   [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/what-will-our-list-of-close-reasons-look-like/4507#4507), and it's unlikely to succeed.

Comment: This has been discussed many times on the mother meta, the team is fairly committed to the current process, reasoning that it is hard for the users of any given site to be *good* at migrating questions to more than a few other sites.

Comment: @dmckee could you give me a link to where this has been discussed on the mother site?

Comment: They start with http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96205/ for Stack Overflow, and there are many "linked" questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered by [the link dmckee gave in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration), in which the exact same feature was proposed on MSO and declined. Migrations to sites other than Math are sufficiently rare that there's no particular need to let ordinary users vote for them. (Moderators have always been able to do this.)

Remember that the first thing to decide when considering whether to migrate a question is, do you think it's off topic here? If you see a question that is off topic, flag it as such, or vote to close if you have that privilege. If you think the question would be appropriate at another site, other than the options given (Meta and Math), leave a comment on the question to indicate that. Alternatively, you can custom-flag the question as "Off topic and possibly suitable for migration to X" or some such thing. **Don't suggest a question for migration unless you believe it's off topic on this site.**

Comment: Also, don't recommend a question for migration unless you're fairly confident that the other site will be happy to receive the question (in its current form).